# 404 err on Rails 3 deploy to AWS... fine except EB doesn't copy /ondeck to /current

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, http-status-code-404, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When I deploy my rails app, I end up with a few errors that result in a nginx 1.2.3 404 error.

During deploy, EB says: "ERROR: Some instances have not responded to commands. Responses were not received from [i-a054e9de]."

I can login to my EC2 and in var/app "mv ondeck to current" then "touch current/tmp/restart.txt" and then the app will properly deploy and work fine. It has all dependencies and is hooked up properly to the RDS database.

The question is:

*How do I get the aws server (elastic beanstalk) to make the final deployment step that will copy ondeck to current?*

Am I missing something in my configuration file? Is there a setting that I accidentally changed in the EB configuration?

BTW, everything was working fine until recently this problem showed up... any thoughts are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same thing happening to me :(

Answer (score 1):

At one point, I did a EB "Rebuild Deployment" which removed the port 443 settings for supporting https: from the Elastic Load Balancer.

When I added the 443 back to the balancer, the deployment started to work properly... i.e. it would finish deployment with a copy from ondeck to current. Problem seems to be solved, although I can't explain why this would be necessary.